# Using context.SaveChanges() in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Hi I'm using the Code first method within Entity Framework using Visual Studio 2012 Could someone tell me if I should add `context.SaveChanges();` at the end of my Seed method within the configuration.cs file in order to successfully update my tables? I can make structural changes using update-database -verbose in the console, but this doesn't update my data.

Answer (score 8):

edit: you do in fact not need to call `SaveChanges`. Thus, this must mean that after the `Seed` method has been called, a call to `SaveChanges` is automatically made. However, it is perhaps useful to note that you *can* call `SaveChanges()` within the `Seed` method if you want, which can be useful when dealing with foreign key relations.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply, I did though manage to populate my tables with initial data without using 'context.SaveChanges();', is this normal?

Comment: Apparently, I was mistaken. I am truly sorry. My answer has been modified.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense because I could actually add data to everything but my foreign key ICollection property, is the 'SaveChanges' call a must for these types of updates?

Comment: Well, I'm not sure but I think so. I guess it depends on the objects stored in the foreign key collection. If you have objects in your foreign key collection that reference a class other than the class they are contained in, I think you need to ensure that the instances of that other class have been saved first. That way you can reference them from the objects in the foreign key collection. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 2):

Initializers that provide `Seed` usually look like this inside...

```
// ...do something - prepare Db, Create etc.
Seed(context); // you override that
context.SaveChanges();
```

...just to clarify further.